# Trying to count all universities in a governorate but many have towns/villages set as the value

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

What I tried at first:

```
select (count(?s) as ?Number_Of_Universities_In_Syria), ?City
WHERE {
?s dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Universities_in_Syria> .
?s dbo:city ?City.
}group by ?City
```

Now I'm trying to get the subdivision of the towns which includes multiple values including the city's name.
Is there a way to fill the ?City column with either dbo:city or dbo:subdivision?

Comment: I do not get the problem. So far you have the number of universities in Syria per city. And you want to get what instead? Can you give an example please?

Comment: and a simple "or" is done either with `{?s dbo:city ?City.} UNION {?s dbo:subdivision ?City.}` or just use a property path, i.e. `?s dbo:city|dbo:subdivision ?City.`

Comment: @UninformedUser the example is there in the code snippet,  when you run it on  [here](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) the result is universities being counted by not only governorates but also villages and towns.
So I'm trying to get the equivalent governorate for each of the town without changing the ones with actual governorate names

Comment: a simple or won't solve the problem, I need to check if the value is a governorate name first then replace the value if it wasn't, otherwise keep it

Comment: this will prefer governorates over cities:`select (count(DISTINCT ?s) as ?Number_Of_Universities_In_Syria), ?City
WHERE {
?s dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Universities_in_Syria> .
?s dbo:city ?City_Or_Governate . 
 {?City_Or_Governate dct:subject ?cat. FILTER(?cat IN (dbc:Cities_in_Syria, dbc:Governorates_of_Syria )) } UNION {?City_Or_Governate a dbo:City}
OPTIONAL {
?City_Or_Governate  dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/dbo:subdivision ?Governate . ?Governate dbo:type dbr:Governorates_of_Syria
}
BIND(COALESCE(?Governate, ?City_Or_Governate) AS ?City)
} group by ?City`

Comment: indeed you have to adapt the triple patterns a bit to cover corner cases - welcome to data heterogenity

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for your effort, the result is much nicer!
But it still has Alexandria (an Egyptian province) which is understandable, there's no way to reach the correct value for it, Latakia (where Arab_Academy_for_Science,_Technology is located) it says Alexandria because that's where the original branch of the university is located
Also seems to skip some values as I've come up with a hard coded solution consisting of a series of replace() statements to replace every odd value with the right governorate name and the numbers were higher for Aleppo and Daraa (both had 6)